# get the height of the large navigation bar programatically iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, large-title

How do I get the height of a large navigationBar? Even when it is small? 
I know that it is 96 points, but when and where can I get this value programatically?

Comment: When? When the navigation bar is large.

Comment: Why do you need the height of a large navigationBar even when it is small?

Comment: @iOSDev I want to implement a scrollToTop method that also shoes the large Title. So I need that height to pass it to the method ´scrollView.setContentOffset(desiredOffset, animated: true)`. I need a point where I can read that height knowing that it is large at that point.

Comment: https://medium.com/@lucabecchetti/calculate-top-distance-status-bar-height-and-navigation-bar-height-of-uiviewcontroller-without-e4dbfe241a77 could be a good lead of track. 